# Passing ruby variable to js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to pass ruby variable to JavaScript function. Here the ruby variable is an active record object.

```
= label = @label // active record object
- @x = 5

= javascript_tag "alert(#{ j(@x.to_json)});" // Working
= javascript_tag "proj.app.custom(#{ j(label.to_json)})" // Not working
```

proj.app.custom is a javascript function.

```
proj.app.custom = function(param) {
};
```

I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: What is `label`? Does `label.inspect.to_s` return something that looks like what `proj.app.custom` would accept? What is `proj.app.custom` and what parameters does it expect?

Comment: "How to pass ruby variable to JavaScript function" - you already know (your example with `@x`).

Comment: @spickermann - I have updated the js

Comment: What is the resulting rendered markup from the "not working" `javascript_tag`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I can't understand ur question

Comment: @Sam: `javascript_tag` renders (is transformed into) an html `<script>` tag, right? Show me what is in the page source in place of the "not working" `javascript_tag`.

Comment: What is `@label`? When you say "not working", can you narrow down the error... Is the error due to the `j(...)`, or the `proj.app.custom`, or `label.to_json`? Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Somebody answered. Thanks

Comment: @Sam: you got lucky this time, but for the future, if someone asks you for additional info, you provide it. I'm not sure why you didn't do that here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `label` contains, but if you want to pass a json you should not escape it:

```
= javascript_tag "proj.app.custom(#{label.to_json})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
= javascript_tag "proj.app.custom(#{ j(@label.to_json)})"
```

I have a feeling that your assignment of `= label = @label` above isn't valid.

Comment: It looks weird, but it is valid :) It will just display the result of the assignment on the page.